# How to group values of columns using PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't find how to group values of 7 MySQL columns.
Columns :

```
ex_MONDAY
ex_TUESDAY
ex_WEDNESDAY
ex_THURSDAY
ex_FRIDAY
ex_SATURDAY
ex_SUNDAY
```

Values are more or less the same exemple

```
15-00035 / 15-00035 / 12-00014 / 11-00004 / 11-00004 / 11-00004 / 11-00004 /
```

I would like it group those values and I could use them in a `while ($z < mysql_num_rows($result))` and as result I would get something like this:

```
15-00035
12-00014
11-00004
```

Because as grouped there is only 3 different values.

Currently i'm using this code but it seems to not work:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT ex_MONDAY,ex_TUESDAY,ex_WEDNESDAY,ex_THURSDAY,ex_FRIDAY,ex_SATURDAY,ex_SUNDAY FROM mytable WHERE week=38 AND year=2015 GROUP BY ex_MONDAY,ex_TUESDAY,ex_WEDNESDAY,ex_THURSDAY,ex_FRIDAY,ex_SATURDAY,ex_SUNDAY");

$fetch=mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo "$fetch[0]"; //returns 15-00035
echo "$fetch[1]"; // returns no value
echo "$fetch[2]"; // returns 11-0004
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` acts on different rows, but not on values on a single row.

Comment: Stop. See normalization. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Kuya, in the absence of aggregation, the *only* reason GROUP BY is *ever* better choice is that it performs faster than DISTINCT. This is, in my view, unfortunate, but there you go.

Comment: @Strawberry if you were me how would you have done your database for store those 7 days?

Comment: @backtrack use a single row for the values plus a row for the day or day of week, then select by week using distinct.

Comment: For example: `day (int 1-7), value_part_a (int, e.g. 11,12, 15), value_part_b (int, e.g. 4,14,35)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PHP functions [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT ex_MONDAY,ex_TUESDAY,ex_WEDNESDAY,ex_THURSDAY,ex_FRIDAY,ex_SATURDAY,ex_SUNDAY FROM mytable WHERE week=38 AND year=2015");
$fetch = array_values(array_unique(mysql_fetch_row($result)));
```

To weed out empty values, additionally use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$fetch = array_values(array_unique(array_filter(mysql_fetch_row($result))));
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work. I get "Notice: Undefined offset: 1" "Notice: Undefined offset: 2" it only shows 15-00035.

Comment: I did not care for the keys. Try the modified solution with `array_values()`.

Comment: It works better no more errors and it shows 15-00035 / 12-00014 / no values. Could it be because I have no values sometimes like in ex_SATURDAY and ex_SUNDAY so it stops? Thanks of your patience

Comment: Are you sure you have more than two values on these lines? I converted your example from above into an array and it worked perfectly. For testing, better use `var_dump($fetch)` or `var_export($fetch)` which exactly show you which key => value combinations are present.

Comment: Yes i'm sure and i've double check in phpmyadmin if I put the query in SQL there is 15-00035 / 11-00004 / 12-00014. var_export($fetch) returns array ( 0 => '15-00035', 1 => '12-00014', 2 => '', )   It's missing 11-00004 strangely

Comment: Do the `var_export($fetch)` on the unmodified fetched row, with `$fetch = mysql_fetch_row($result);`. What do you get?

Comment: Inside the while I get that: array ( 0 => '15-00035', 1 => '15-00035', 2 => '15-00035', 3 => '12-00014', 4 => '12-00014', 5 => '', 6 => '', ) <br> array ( 0 => '15-00035', 1 => '15-00035', 2 => '15-00035', 3 => '15-00035', 4 => '15-00035', 5 => '', 6 => '', ) <br> array ( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => '11-00004', 3 => '11-00004', 4 => '11-00004', 5 => '', 6 => '', ) Here we have our 11-00004 :-)

Comment: So on the first row it would give you 15-00035 / 12-00014 / '', on the second 15-00035 / '' / -, on the third 11-00004 / '' / -. Does it not?

Comment: To weed out the empty strings, you can use array_filter(); i add that to the answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting exactly what you are saying with the filter set. Do you know how it could display the 3 unique values stored inside a variable i could use in a while for exemple?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do there. Anyways, could you please accept the answer, as to me it seems the question is answered now?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help already. Your solution is 90% what i'm looking for. What i would like is it has the 3 unique values inside a variable. Exemple $fetch[0] $fetch[1] and $fetch[2] got the 3 unique values so I can do a while loop with $fetch[$z] $z++; and it will show on screen. 15-00035 12-00014 11-00004

Comment: `foreach ($fetch as $key => $value) {...}`? Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Thank you I think I can make something work out with that. Good day !